# How can a variable under sampling change its value in R?

Tags: r, variables, sample

This is probably a very basic question but how do you make a variable change its value in `R` as follows?

Suppose that I want to sample a value from the set `{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}` five times.

I first let `var <- sample(c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), size = 1)` to define the sample, and then entered `var` five times into the console.

However, `var` keeps giving the same number over and over again. What could I do to prevent this?

Note: due to the context of this problem, changing `size = 5` doesn't work.

Comment: You are sampling pseudo-randomly 1 element from a vector of 5 elements with your command.
Then you are storing it into an object called `var` if you replicate the random sample you will get probably another value but you'll be able to use it only if you will store into another object.
Anyway your question is a little bit confusing. I don't understand exactly which is your goal

Comment: Your command works for me and produces different numbers for multiple assignments of `var`. Maybe you have fixed your `seed` for each call to the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do , `set.seed(NULL)` and re-run your code you will receive a different value each time. However, if you do something like `set.seed(1729)`, `set.seed(42)` etc., you will get same number again.

In my system , running `set.seed(NULL)` results below:

```
> set.seed(NULL)
> var <- sample(c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), size = 1)
> var
[1] -2
> var <- sample(c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), size = 1)
> var
[1] 1
```

If I try `set.seed(1729)` and re-run the code, I will receive:

```
> set.seed(1729)
> var <- sample(c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), size = 1)
> var
[1] 0
> var <- sample(c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), size = 1)
> var
[1] 0
```

The seed number which we choose is the starting point used in the generation of a sequence of random numbers, which is why we obtain the same results given the same seed number.

**Note from the documentation** `?set.seed`:

> Initially, there is no seed; a new one is created from the current
>   time and the process ID when one is required. Hence different sessions
>   will give different simulation results, by default. However, the seed
>   might be restored from a previous session if a previously saved
>   workspace is restored.